# Library for splitting text content based on overflow

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm looking for a NPM package that has a function of splitting text based on overflow, more specifically for DOM (I do have the width and height of the container, but I use the Verdana font for the text). For example, given this:

```
.----------------.
| some text that |
| is too large   | for this div
`----------------´
```

This should output:

```
['some text that is too large', 'for this div']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ["text-fit" NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/textfit). You can pass the width
and height of the container as arguments, along with the font family
and font size.

For example:

```
const textFit = require('text-fit');
 
const text = 'some text that is too large for this div';
 
const containerWidth = 500; const containerHeight = 100;
 
const fontFamily = 'Verdana'; const fontSize = 16;
 
const lines = textFit(text, { containerWidth, containerHeight, fontFamily, fontSize });
 
console.log(lines);
```

This should output:

```
[ 'some text that is too large', 'for this div' ]
```

Comment: textfit looks great! On the other side, line-breaker does not take font into account, if I understand correctly? I would encourage you to post these two solutions as two separate answers, so that voters can vote for one and not the other, for instance, allowing the best answers to bubble up. :-)

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation @NicolasRaoul. I updated my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Another popular NPM package for splitting text based on overflow is
"[line-breaker NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-breaker)". It provides a function "breakLines()" that
takes a string of text and returns an array of lines that can fit
within a given width.

For example:

```
const lineBreaker = require('line-breaker'); 
const text = 'some text that is too large for this div'; 
const width = 500; 
const lines = lineBreaker(text, { width }); 
 
console.log(lines);
```

This should output:

```
[ 'some text that is too large', 'for this div' ]
```